# Diferença hashmap e arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Alguém poderia me explicar a diferença entre `HashMap`e `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `ArrayList`

é um conjunto de elementos de um tipo definido. É uma estrutura ordenada de dados, ou seja, os valores podem ser acessados por seus índices.

Exemplo:

```
ArrayList<string> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("Stack");
lista.add("Overflow");
```

Isso seria algo como

```
Index | Elemento
  0   | "Stack"
  1   | "Overflow"
```

Estes elementos podem ser acessados pelo seu índice

```
String str1 = lista.get(0); //str1 receberá "Stack"
```

### `HashMap`

É um conjunto de pares de chave-valor, para cada elemento (valor) salvo num `HashMap` deve existir uma **chave única** atrelada a ele. Os elementos num `HashMap` devem ser acessados por suas chaves.

Exemplo:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "Stack");
hashMap.put(5, "Overflow");
```

Isso seria algo como:

```
Key | Value
 1  | "Stack"
 5  | "Overflow"
```

Estes elementos podem ser acessados pela chave

```
String str = map.get(5); //str receberá "Overflow"
```

Comment: Agradecido pela a explicação, consegui compreender perfeitamente.